# Manually deleting multile files in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to delete multiple files with one command using powershell. i.e in unix you can do `rm file1 file2` but when I try it in powershell I get "Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'file2'". Same if I use del.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the file paths with a comma, like this.

```
Remove-Item "test1.txt", "test2.txt"
```

There are also options for using wildcard characters, like

```
Remove-Item "test*.txt"
```

this will remove all files that match the pattern.

You can check more details in the [command's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.2)